# "sudo" prompts for password in terminal that has started "agetty ttyS0 9600" instead of the "serial" terminal

Tags: linux, agetty

Broader context, I'm using QEMU+KVM to virtualize an ubuntu machine like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -enable-kvm \
    -m 2048 \
    -nic none \
    -vnc :5 \
    -hda test-vm.raw \
    -device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0 \
    -serial unix:/tmp/console.sock,server,nowait
```

I'm using `/tmp/console.sock` to login into the virtual machine via "serial":

`socat stdin,raw,echo=0,escape=0x11 "unix-connect:/tmp/console.sock"`

This works without any major problems.

However, when I'm entering `sudo su` the prompt for the password appears on the terminal that has started the `agetty` process (not the serial console).

I know that starting `agetty` from a terminal isn't how you would start it normally.

However, I'm very curious as to how this happens and how I can start `agetty` from the terminal without it having *any* connection (`sudo` asking for the password on the terminal that has started `agetty` leads me to believe that there *is* some connection) to the terminal that has started it.

I already tried:

```
$ nohup agetty ttyS0 9600 &
$ disown <pid>
```

Without success.

Would love to know the underlying mechanic that is at play here and how I can possibly remedy the issue*.

*As said, I know that starting `agetty` from a normal terminal isn't how you would use the program. I'm still interested in how this happens and how you could prevent `agetty` from acting this way.

Comment: I'm curious, if you launch with `setsid agetty ttyS0 9600 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` does the same behaviour happen?

Comment: @ChrisDown Thanks for your comment. `setsid agetty ttyS0 9600 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` works! `agetty ttyS0 9600 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` does not but `setsid agetty ttyS0 9600` works again.

Comment: Great! I will write it up as an answer, then.

Comment: @ChrisDown Excellent! Thank you so much for your in-depth answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `agetty` from your terminal, it becomes the session leader of a new session and inherits the controlling terminal from which it was invoked. As a result, any commands executed within the virtual machine inherit the controlling terminal, impacting the behavior of utilities like sudo. The terminal where agetty was started from is being used as the controlling terminal, which is why sudo prompts for the password there.

A terminal session is typically associated with a Session ID (SID), and each process running in the session belongs to this SID. The process that sets up the SID is called the session leader. When agetty is started, it becomes a session leader for a new session and inherits the controlling terminal. Therefore, when you run `sudo` in the virtual machine, the prompt for the password appears on the terminal that initiated the agetty process.

To sever this connection between agetty and your terminal, you can use the setsid command:

```
setsid agetty ttyS0 9600
```

The `setsid` command creates a new session, setting the invoked command as the session leader for the new session. This action also sets the command to have no controlling terminal, thus ensuring that processes spawned in the new session (like `sudo`) do not inherit the original controlling terminal. From [the POSIX specification of `setsid`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html):

> The setsid() function shall create a new session, if the calling process is not a process group leader. Upon return the calling process shall be the session leader of this new session, shall be the process group leader of a new process group, and shall have no controlling terminal. The process group ID of the calling process shall be set equal to the process ID of the calling process. The calling process shall be the only process in the new process group and the only process in the new session.

You might ask why `sudo` cares about this controlling terminal in the first place. The `sudo` command does its best to interact directly with the user invoking it without going through any intermediaries, which is different from merely writing to stdout or stderr. Writing to stdout or stderr might risk leaking sensitive information, or another process might eavesdrop on this data.

The controlling terminal is considered closer to a direct line to the user, making it a more secure channel for user-sensitive operations like password entry. When sudo is invoked, it typically writes the password prompt directly to the terminal, bypassing stdout or stderr. This is done to ensure that the password prompt is both visible to the user and not accidentally redirected, logged, or otherwise captured.